# How to attach window.close to cntrl+w keypress event in a xul window?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, dom-events, xul

I have a XUL window, and I want the <kbd>cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> hotkey to close the window, but when I attach:

```
window.addEventListener("keypress", function(ev) {
  GM_log("onkeypress handler: \n"
  + "keyCode property: " + ev.keyCode + "\n"
  + "which property: " + ev.which + "\n"
  + "charCode property: " + ev.charCode + "\n"
  + "Character Key Pressed: "
  + String.fromCharCode(ev.charCode) + "\n");
}, true);
```

to the page, it treats pressing 'w' and 'cntrl+w' the same, charCode 119.. how can I determine that <kbd>cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> was pressed so that I may `window.close()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XUL this is done by:

```
<keyset>
   <key id="key_close" key="W" modifiers="control" oncommand="window.close();" />
</keyset>
```

see: [xul tutorial - keyboar shortcuts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Keyboard_Shortcuts)

Comment: [It doesn't work if your window has a browser element with gmail.com loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099128/how-to-get-key-event-in-xul-independent-of-the-current-website).

Answer (score 1):

use ev.ctrlKey to detect if the ctrl key is pressed (it is a boolean value).